# Android Studio (Electric Eel) - 413 Google Login not working / App Quality Insights

Tags: firebase, android-studio, crashlytics, android-studio-electric-eel, app-quality-insights

In Android Studio, the IDE itself (not a project related question), you can login with your Google account to take advantage of features like Firebase Crashlytics. When I hit accept on the OAuth screen on Google it attempts to navigate to a callback URL to pass the token back to the IDE but I get a 413 error:

> This page isn’t working
> If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
> HTTP ERROR 413

Google Login callback: http://localhost:55244/Callback?code=***

Firebase Login callback: http://localhost:55838/Callback?code=***

Answer (score 1):

This type of error can occur when there are too many cookies linked to the localhost site (error 413 = Request Entity Too Large).

By purging the browser cookies for the localhost site, the problem should be solved on your computer.

If you are using Google Chrome, to purge cookies from a site, you can follow the steps described in this link: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop